# How is interaction with CDC device with no interface endpoints working?

Tags: bootloader, uploading, digispark

I'm working on uploading to [Digispark board](http://digistump.com/products/1). It uses [micronucleus](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus) bootloader and i can see [uploader code](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/blob/master/commandline/library/micronucleus_lib.c). I've modified it a bit to see interfaces and endpoints count:

```
    nucleus->device = usb_open(dev);

    // added by me - start
    int interfaces, endpoints, j;
    struct usb_interface_descriptor *interface = NULL;

    interfaces = dev->config->bNumInterfaces;
    fprintf(stderr, "Found interfaces: %i\n", interfaces);

    interface = &(dev->config->interface[0].altsetting[0]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Endpoints: %i\n", interface->bNumEndpoints);
    // added by me - end

    // get nucleus info
    unsigned char buffer[4];
    int res = usb_control_msg(nucleus->device, USB_ENDPOINT_IN| USB_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_RECIP_DEVICE, 0, 0, 0, (char *)buffer, 4, MICRONUCLEUS_USB_TIMEOUT);
```

I wonder how it's working because interface #0 has no endpoints:

```
$./micronucleus --type intel-hex /tmp/Start.ino.hex 
> Please plug in the device ... 
> Press CTRL+C to terminate the program.
Found interfaces: 1
Endpoints: 0
> Device is found!
connecting: 40% complete
> Device has firmware version 1.6
> Available space for user applications: 6012 bytes
> Suggested sleep time between sending pages: 8ms
> Whole page count: 94  page size: 64
> Erase function sleep duration: 752ms
parsing: 60% complete
> Erasing the memory ...
erasing: 80% complete
> Starting to upload ...
writing: 100% complete
>> Micronucleus done. Thank you!
```

Usually i expect interface to have 2 endpoints (in & out from [usb.h](https://github.com/libusb/libusb-compat-0.1/blob/master/libusb/usb.h)):

```
#define USB_ENDPOINT_IN         0x80
#define USB_ENDPOINT_OUT        0x00
```

Can anyone explain me how `usb_control_msg(nucleus->device, USB_ENDPOINT_IN| USB_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_RECIP_DEVICE, 0, 0, 0, (char *)buffer, 4, MICRONUCLEUS_USB_TIMEOUT);` is working without endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micronucleus uses control transfers to upload code (it's not a CDC device). You don't need an endpoint for control transfers - they use the implicit endpoint 0 that is always present whether you define one or not.

You only need to define endpoints for interfaces that want to communicate using bulk, interrupt or isochronous transfers.

```
Bus 003 Device 073: ID 16d0:0753 MCS Digistump DigiSpark
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x16d0 MCS
  idProduct          0x0753 Digistump DigiSpark
  bcdDevice            1.02
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           18
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
Device Status:     0x18c0
  (Bus Powered)
  Debug Mode
```

[image]